# django javascript behaving oddly

Tags: javascript, django

I've a button called "Add new usage", basically, when user clicks it, it'll display the form, a pretty simple behavior, but I don't understand how it always triggers the action in the form underneath it, I'm very confused, here's my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <p style="padding-left: 0.5cm;">
        <button id="create_new_spa" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" 
                onclick="javascript:show_create_new_usage_form();" type='submit' 
                onclick="this.disabled=true">
                    Add new usage
        </button>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="row" id="create_new_usage_form" style="display:none">
    <form method="post" action="/purchasing/item_info_spa_details_update/">
    </form>
</div>
```

And here's my js code:

```
{% block jquery2 %}
function show_create_new_usage_form() {
    $("#create_new_usage_form").show();
}{% endblock %}
```

So, I was expecting to click the "Add new usage" button, then the form shows up, however, now it displays form instantly, and following that, instantly within in like 20 ms, it quickly goes to action in the form, doesn't allow the user to see the form, and then quickly hides the form again.

I cannot see anything wrong with the code, please help!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1) The onclick attribute is duplicated. 2) The form will be submitted if you do not prevent default.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT** This answer is not correct. I leave it here for the insight from the comments below.

*the following original statement is not correct see comments below:*
The `show()` function of jquery is used to reveal an element for a given time (default 400ms).

See documentation here:

http://api.jquery.com/show/

You could e.g. use:

```
.css( "display", "inline" )
```

to show the form on click and then hide it with a dedicated function that is called via action.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea, also, I just figured out why this strange behaviro happens, it's due to that I missed a </form> somewhere in that page, any ideas on a good html editor that can help me with silly errors like this? Right now, I'm using PyCharm since I'm developing in Django.

Comment: "*The `show()` function of jquery is used to reveal an element for a given time*". This is not what it does at all. The `duration` specifies the length of the animation used to show the object. It doesn't - as you suggest - show it for some duration and then hide it again.

Comment: Oh right you are correct, should have read the documentation through to the end myself :(... My answer was posted to quick. The answer should not be accepted then. The solution to the question was another one anyway.

Comment: @fishercoder could you please unaccept my answer, as it is partly wrong and not the solution to your problem!?

Comment: Thanks, I just did. But I appreciate your quick post, and I thought I should also have designed more depth before asking here. Thanks anyway.